# How to apply typecheck with Smart-Pointers and Subclasses

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I had a first look into smart-pointers and try to apply it with polymorphism.

Lets think of a parent-class Auto and subclasses Van, Estate, Convertible, ....

I have a list of element-type Auto. I insert objects of the subclasses into it.

```
std::list <Auto *> lst;
lst.push_back (new Van ());
```

If I get it out if do a typecheck to handle it in a different way.

Old code with raw-pointers.

```
 Auto *a = list.first ();  // returns Auto*
 if (typeid (*a) == typeid (Van))  
 { // do van things }
 ...
```

That is working.

But it is not if I switch to shared_ptrs on every level.

```
std::shared_ptr <Auto> a = list.first ()
```

typeid is always shared_ptr of Auto. I expect shared_ptr of the subclass.

It works if I do it with the core of the smart-ptr.

```
Auto *p = a.get ();
typeid (*p)  // is Van if it is a Van
```

But I am sure that is not the most elegant way. How to do it ẃith smart-pointers??

EDIT:

I need to

- have 1 list for all type of cars
- if I take it out handle it separately.

EDIT:

I replaces polymorphism with the word subclasses.
Because it is not about sending a message to an objects and it performs regarding its type but more about typechecking externally.

Thanks for help, chis

Comment: Get rid of `typeid`. Whatever you're doing with `typeid`, you're doing it wrong. Properly-written C++ code does not use `typeid`, but rather virtual method calls. Which work perfectly fine with smart pointers.

Comment: Make your title describe your question, please. A lot of your titles just briefly list a couple of language features. I can only see a few good ones out of 42!

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Well, most properly written C++ :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `dynamic_cast`, never `typeid`:

```
if (Van* item = dynamic_cast<Van*>(a)) {
    item->doVanThings(); // do van things 
} //else try other casts
```

Even better would be to let polymorphism differentiate, since you're already using polymorphism anyway:

```
class Auto {
public:
    virtual void doThings() = 0;
};

class Van : public Auto {
public:
    void doThings() override {
        // do van things
    }
};

class Estate : public Auto {
public:
    void doThings() override {
        // do estate things
    }
};

class Convertible : public Auto {
public:
    void doThings() override {
        // do convertible things
    }
};
```

```
std::list<Auto *> lst;
...
Auto *a = lst.first();
a->doThings();
```

```
std::list<std::shared_ptr<Auto>> lst;
...
std::shared_ptr<Auto> a = lst.first();
a->doThings();
```

Comment: Ahh, that's true to use `override` in c++11 and chris did tag it with that.

Comment: [visitor-pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/design-patterns/4579/visitor-pattern/15127/visitor-pattern-example-in-c#t=201612160136169983591) may allow to avoid to have too many virtual method in base class.